# Are the inflectional endings in English known to have evolved from separate words or do they go too far back into PIE to know?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, inflection, affixes

English isn't a highly inflected language, but it did evolve from one and still has at least: -s, -es; -ed, -ing; -er, -est; for nouns, verbs, and adjectives.

Do we know if these all evolved from separate words, or do they go too far back into PIE to know?

Comment: I believe that all of these suffixes have been suffixes since PIE times.

Comment: One could argue about the 3sgPres _-s_; _-(e)th_ was PIE *_-t_, but I'm not sure where the Scandinavian _-s_ comes from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

English is generally regarded as having the following 7 inflectional suffixes. All of them have been suffixes since Proto-Indoeuropean, but most have followed a rather circuitous path along the way. This is rough outline:

1. **plural *-s*:**
   < AS *-as* 'masc. *a*-stem nom.-acc. pl.'
   < PGmc *-anz* 'acc. pl.'
   < PIE *-(o)ns* 'acc. pl.'
2. **third person singular *-s*:**
   < AS *-st* '2nd person sg.' (2sg was leveled with 3sg by analogy with ON)
   < PGmc *-zi* '2nd person sg.'
   < PIE *-si* '2nd person sg.'
3. **past tense/participle *-ed*:**
   < AS *-ode* 'class 2 weak verb past'
   < PGmc *-ode* 'class 2 weak verb past'
   < PIE *-to-* 'adjectival derivational suffix'
4. **past participle *-en***
   < ON *-inn* 'past part.'
   < PGmc *-īnaz* 'adjectival derivational suffix'
   < PIE *-nos* 'adjectival derivational suffix'
5. **progressive *-ing*:**
   < collapse of AS *-ing* 'gerund' and *-ende* 'present participle'
   < PGmc *-ung-* 'gerund' / *-and-* 'pres. part.'
   < PIE *-enkw-* 'deverbative' / *-nt-* 'active pres. part.'
6. **comparative *-er*:**
   < AS *-ra* 'comparative'
   < PGmc *-iz(o)/-oz(o)* 'comparative'
   < [PIE *-yos-* 'elative'](https://books.google.com/books?id=NlExDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA316&ots=eOh9zN2Hn1&dq=proto%20germanic%20comparative%20superlative%20proto%20indo%20european&pg=PA316#v=onepage&q=proto%20germanic%20comparative%20superlative%20proto%20indo%20european&f=false)
7. **superlative *-est*:**
   < AS *-st* 'superlative'
   < PGmc *-istaz/-ostaz* 'superlative'
   < PIE  [*-yos-* + *-tas/-tos* 'nominalizer'](https://books.google.com/books?id=NlExDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA316&ots=eOh9zN2Hn1&dq=proto%20germanic%20comparative%20superlative%20proto%20indo%20european&pg=PA316#v=onepage&q=proto%20germanic%20comparative%20superlative%20proto%20indo%20european&f=false)

Comment: Yes, I need to document my references.

Comment: I thought the "-ed" weak suffix was thought to have possibly been derived from suffixation of a separate word like "do". The Wikipedia article "[Germanic weak verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_weak_verb#Origin_of_dental_suffix)" says "The origin of the dental suffix is uncertain. Perhaps the most commonly held theory is that it evolved out of a periphrastic construction with the verb to do"

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I've seen that too, and it's probably worth adding to the answer. Part of the problem is that past tense *-ed* and past participle *-ed* seem to have had different sources, and then merged (kind of like the two *-ing*s)

Comment: Doesn't possessive "'s" come from "his," e.g., "the dog, his bone"->"the dog's bone?"

Comment: @Ben Crowell. I don't think so. I intentionally left out the possessive since it's a clitic unlike the inflectional suffixes; that said, possessive *-s* seems to come from AS *-es*, and in turn the Proto-Germanic genitive singulars with *-s*.

Comment: I don't think 's becomes a clitic until very recent times. Genitive singular -os or -es is common IE.

Comment: Clearly the modern English possessive NP clitic is a reflex of IE genitives in _-s_. And I would include Infinitive as an inflection; suffix Zero, with suppletive _be_. Otherwise you can't distinguish present tense from infinitive in sentences like _They make Mary pay Bill,_ and _Be a good boy_.

Comment: Oh I just realized I forgot to include possessive *'s*, even if it's technically a clitic I'm still interested in it in exactly the same way as with the rest so I feel it belongs in the group.

Comment: What about the -eth and -est of archaic verb forms?